# Django class inheritance to create table tables

Tags: python, django

I'm beginning to learn Django and setting up my models for a MySQL database. I'd like one of my classes to inherit another class so that the properties carry on to the table.

```
from django.db import models

class Images(models.Model):
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    caption     = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date        = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    url         = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'images'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category

class Videos(Images):

    provider_list   = (('YU','YouTube'),('VI','Vimeo'))
    provider        = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=provider_list)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'videos'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category
```

When I run python manage.py syncdb however, the table "videos" only has a primary ID column and a provider column. Is it necessary to redeclare all of the columns from Images and set up Videos as a completely independence class or is there anyway I can inherit all of these columns into the Videos class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

1) You can consider using abstract base class

2) Use full caps for constants in your choices

To answer your questions you do not need to redeclare all the columns.

```
from django.db import models

class BaseMedia(models.Model):
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    caption     = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date        = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    url         = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Images(BaseMedia):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'images'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category

class Videos(BaseMedia):

    PROVIDER_LIST_CHOICES   = (('YU','YouTube'),('VI','Vimeo'))
    provider        = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PROVIDER_LIST_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'videos'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category
```